# XSL - How to make value into multiple lines within a cell of Excel?

Tags: xslt

I need to apply XSL to XML and generate report in Excel.

With following sample, becasue the source xml contains "&#xa", it creates newline. It ends up with writing 111 in row1 and 222 in row2 of Excel.

What I want to achieve is to "make the value into multiple lines **WITHIN A CELL**."

Could you please, help on this?

XML

```
<test value="111&#xa;222" />
```

XSL

```
<xsl:value-of select="./@value" />
```

Result

```
Excel Row 1 : 111
Excel Row 2 : 222
```

**Resolved with following approach** (edited)

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', @value, '&quot;')"/>
```

Comment: Can you try `&#xb;` instead of `&#xa;`?

Comment: As an addtional information, I cannot modify the source xml. I tried <xsl:value-of select="translate(./@value,'&#xa;','&#xb;')" />, then it failed to generate output...

Comment: So which Excel XML format is that? If you create a cell with multiple lines in Excel and save it in your target XML format, how does that XML then represent the cell and its multi-line value?

Comment: I'm afraid if I understand your question correctly...(well I don't), but what I need to do is to apply xsl to xml that is generated by a system and make it in csv format. I use Excel 2016 to open the csv.

Comment: If you create a new Excel file (with Excel), manually type in a multi-line value, save the file, rename the `.xlsx` to `.zip`, open that, look at the contents (there will be multiple subfolders and XML files - look for the one that contains your test value), you will find which character Excel itself uses to split lines in a cell. That's the character you should use, too. (I believe it's `0xb`, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: CSV usually wraps such multi-line values in double quotes so if you really use XSLT to create CSV and you want that `@value` attribute to represent a column value then try to use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', @value, '&quot;')"/>`. Of course if you expect the attribute value to also contain double quotes you need to escape, not sure whether CSV does that by duplicating them.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for letting me the detail. I tried it but was not able to find necessary information...

Comment: @Martin Honnen yes!yes!yes! that resolved my issue! Thanks!